Hermite polynomial and Gaussian random variable
The following formula is well known: $E[H_k(X,E[X])H_q(Y,E[Y])]=\delta_{kq}E[XY]^k$ for a joint Gaussian r.v. $(X, Y),$ $H_k$ are Hermite polynomiale.
Is there a generalization for this to a joint Gaussian vector r.v. $(X_1,...X_r)?$ (where we have the product of $r$ Hermite polynomials, there is Isserlis' theorem but this covers first order Hermilte polynomial: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isserlis%27_theorem)

$\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}} \newcommand{\val}{\mathop{val}}$Yes, there is such a generalization. I will discuss a special case where all $X_i$ are mean zero and variance one (but might have arbitrary correlations) - a more general result can be obtained in a similiar way, but the final expression is a bit more messy.
It appears to me that this result is well known among those who well-know it. It is not my primary research area, so I do not know the canonical reference for it (and I would appreciate if somebody here can provide). The closest result that I found a proof of in the literature is a calculation in [1] - where even further special case with all $X_i$ being equal is handled. I will present a slightly different method, following a standard proof of Isserli's theorem via generating function.
Let $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, I)$ and $X_i = \langle u_i, X \rangle$ for some vectors $(u_1, \ldots u_k)$ each with unit norm.
Consider a family $\mathcal{F}$ of all multigraphs on $[k]$ without self-loops, and with degree sequence $(n_1, \ldots n_k)$. For a multigraph $G \in \mathcal{F}$, and a pair of vertices $e \in \binom{[k]}{2}$, let $\nu(e) \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ be the multiplicty of an edge $e$ in $G$. We define
$$
\val(G) := \prod_{(i, j) \in E(G)} \frac{1}{\nu(i,j)!}\langle u_i, u_j \rangle^{\nu(i,j)} = \prod_{(i,j) \in E(G)} \frac{1}{\nu(i,j)!} \E [X_i X_j]^{\nu(i,j)}.
$$
Claim
For a multivariate gaussian distribution as above, we have
$$
\E \left[\prod_i H_{n_i} (X_i)\right] = \left(\prod_i n_i!\right) \sum_{G \in \mathcal{F}} \val(G). \label{eq:expr-1} \tag{1}
$$
Note that when all $n_i = 1$, this indeed reduces to  the Isserli's theorem, since $\mathcal{F}$ just contains a set of all perfect matchings on $[k]$.
Proof.
We will rely on the generating function for Hermite polynomials:
$$
\exp(xt - t^2/2) = \sum_n H_n(x) \frac{t^n}{n!}.
$$
Now to calculate $\E \prod H_{n_i}(X_i)$, we can look at
$$
\exp(\sum_i (X_i \lambda_i - \lambda_i^2/2)) = \prod_i\left[\sum_n H_n(x) \frac{\lambda_i^{n}}{n!}\right],
$$
expanding the right hand side, the coefficient corresponding to the monomial $\prod_i \lambda_i^{n_i}$ is exactly $\prod_i \frac{H_{n_i}(X_i)}{n_i!}$.
On the other hand
$$
\begin{align}
\E\exp(\sum_i X_i \lambda_i - \lambda_i^2/2) & = \E \left[\exp(\langle \sum_i \lambda_i u_i, X\rangle)\right] \exp(-\sum_i \lambda_i^2/2) \\
& = \exp(\|\sum_i u_i \lambda_i\|_2^2/2 - \sum_i \lambda_i^2/2 )\\
& = \exp(\sum_{i\not=j} \langle u_i, u_j \rangle \lambda_i \lambda_j).
\end{align}
$$
We can now expand this, and collect the term correspodning to $\prod_i \lambda_i^{n_i}$. We need only to focus on homogenous part of degree $D = \sum n_i$, i.e.
$$
\frac{1}{(D/2)!} (\sum_{i \not= j} \langle u_i, u_j \rangle \lambda_i \lambda_j)^{D/2},
$$
and indeed, after expanding $(\sum_{i \not= j} \langle u_i, u_j \rangle \lambda_i \lambda_j)^{D/2}$ each multigraph $G \in \mathcal{F}$ shows up exactly $\frac{(D/2)!}{\prod_e (\nu(e)!)}$ times.
A (slightly) different expression
A related combinatorial expression, in the spirit of how it is phrased in [1] is the following.
Let $D = \sum_i n_i$ and consider a colored set of vertices $[D]$, where vertices $\{1, \ldots, n_1\} \subset [D]$  are of color $1$, vertices $\{n_1 + 1, \ldots n_1 + n_2\} \subset [D]$ of color $2$, and so on. Let $\pi : [D] \to [k]$ be a map assigning a color in $[k]$ to a vertex in $[D]$. Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a class of all perfect matchings on $[D]$ with no monochromatic edges, and for a perfect martching $M \in \mathcal{M}$, let
$$
\val(M) := \prod_{(i, j) \in M} \E[X_{\pi(i)} X_{\pi(j)}],
$$
then
$$
\E[\prod_i H_{n_i}(X_i)] = \sum_{M \in \mathcal{M}} \val(M). \label{eq:expr-2} \tag{2}
$$
The equivalence between \eqref{eq:expr-1} and \eqref{eq:expr-2} can be established by a simple bijective argument.
[1] : Combinatorial applications of Hermite polynomials, R. Azor, J. Gillis and J.D. Victor
